# Cambodian datetime format in System.Globalization is wrong?

Tags: .net, globalization

In Cambodian, the locale is **kh-KH**, datetime format is **dd/MM/yyyy**. But the .NET Framework globalization is using **km-KH** and the datetime format displayed is **yyyy-MM-dd**.

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("km-kh");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(ci)); 
//Will display in yyyy-MM-dd format
```

Not surprisingly, Windows itself is using the same datetime format (yyyy-MM-dd) which is not what Cambodians are using. When I googled "kh-KH", there is no matching result of it, most of them are "km-KH", it seems like "km-KH" is the international standard but why the giant software vendor would implement a wrong datetime format of it?

I am seriously confused, who is right, who is wrong? I tend to believe the cambodian themselves are correct but why Microsoft made this kind of "mistake"? Or am I just making mistakes in some way?

I would appreciate if anyone can solve my confusions here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why? Looks like an honest mistake; it's worth letting them know if you have genuine local knowledge.

Comment: Maybe they looked at [this map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country#Map), couldn't find Cambodia on there and defaulted it to something. It is possible to report it somewhere I would assume. Whether or not something happens because of it is another matter.

Comment: This "question" reads as argumentative.

Comment: Well, yes, Inuyasha. But what I am after is that why there are confusions in the first place, why Microsoft implemented the datetime format that is not what Cambodians are using. Thanks.

Comment: @schrodinger'scode, you would have to ask *them*

Answer (score 0):

I think date time format mostly we are using: dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy in Cambodia.

But I saw a mistake in the post you mention, it's the local: "kh-KH" is wrong, it's "km-KH".

Please have a look at: http://osify.com/2012/11/cambodia-technical-identifier-code-to-be-aware/#.UNK72azp574

Answer (score 0):

The locale in both `Windows and .NET` is km-KH, not kh-KH; I suspect the incorrect results are related to this somehow.

Whoever is creating kh-KH should check CultureInfo.Name to see what was actually created. I suspect some errant fallback logic is ultimately responsible.